# Write to file using an implicit do loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran2003

I need a help about implicit do loop in Fortran.
This is my simple code:

```
Program Simple

Implicit none

Integer::i,j
Integer,parameter::N=2,M=3
Real,dimension(N,M)::Pot

Open(1,File='First.txt',Status='old')

    Read(1,'(M(f3.1,1x))') ((Pot(i,j),j=1,M),i=1,N)

Close(1)

Open(2,File='Second.txt',Status='Unknown')

    Write(2,'(M(i0,1x,i0,1x,f3.1,1x))') ((i,j,Pot(i,j),j=1,M),i=1,N)

Close(2)

Stop
End program Simple
```

This is the file `First.txt`:

```
1.1 1.2 1.3
2.1 2.2 2.3
```

When I try to execute this program I got a this message:

```
Unexpected element 'N' in format string
Unexpected element 'M' in format string
```

I want to keep the name of integer variables N and M in write statement.
Is there any way to also keep their values from declaration part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `M` and `N` in the string (as characters), not as variables. In order to use the variables you need to write their values into the format string:

```
character(len=128) :: fmtString
!...
write(fmtString,*) M
fmtString = '('//trim(adjustl(fmtString))//'(f3.1,1x))'
Read(1,fmtString) ((Pot(i,j),j=1,M),i=1,N)
```

And similarly for the `write` statement.

However, you can probably use list-directed input (`Read(1,*)`) for the input, and let Fortran figure out the exact format.

Instead of this string manipulation you can use `(*(f3.1,1x))` in modern compilers, or if you have an old one just specify a very large number, e.g. `(99999(f3.1,1x))`. In both cases, the correct number of values will be printed. However, this will result into writing all `m*n` values in one single line [thanks @agentp for pointing this out].

Comment: in this case simply using * will put all `m*n` values one one line i think

Comment: That helps a lot!
Correct form is in edited question.

Comment: @JohnCorn please don't do that. If you edit your question like this, nobody else will understand it anymore.